# Is it is possible to "set" a list to a ComboBox, wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

Hi i know its possible to do this with lists however is it possible to do this with Comboboxes? Is there anything similar to the set function?

I have tried using set with a Combo box but i receive the following error:
    AttributeError: 'ComboBox' object has no attribute 'Set'

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can call SetItems(myList) to put a list into a ComboBox, overwriting what's already in it.

EDIT: The most common method to create a list in a combobox's list is like this:

```
myList = ["dog", "cat", "hamster"]
cbo = wx.ComboBox(self, choices=myList)
```

But since ComboBox inherits from ItemContainer, you can also do it like this complete example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        myList = ["dog", "cat", "hamster"]
        cbo = wx.ComboBox(panel)
        cbo.SetItems(myList)

        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ComboBox-class.html

> `__init__(parent, id, value, pos, size, choices, style, validator, name)`

```
combobox = wx.ComboBox(self, choices=myList)
```

Comment: @Mike Driscoll It could be interesting to note that the combobox method to set a list into an already-created combobox, SetItems, is not listed in the class method in wxpython docs linked by Steven. This method is neither cited, not once, in wxPython in Action book... So I understand the OP (gave a +1) because even the book makes you believe that the way is using Set that in fact does not work for comboboxes. I actually made an annotation on my book to remember each time I was consulting it.

Comment: @joaquin Set may have worked for the old version that Robin's book was written for. The SetItems method shows up if you go up the inheritance hierarchy on Steven's link. Just click the ItemContainer link at the top of the page. But yes, it is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your are asking for a method to add new items "at runtime"? ie after the form is created? See the code below if so ;-)

```
   def UpdateCitiesCombo(self):
    self.cmbCities.Clear()
    pc = PostalCode()
    if self.txtPostalCode.Value:
        cities = pc.GetFromCode(int(self.txtPostalCode.Value))
        for city in cities:
            self.cmbCities.Append(city[2])

    items = self.cmbCities.GetItems()

    index = -1
    try:
        if self.customer.city != "":
            index = items.index(self.customer.city)
        else:
            index = 0

        self.cmbCities.SetSelection(index)

    except ValueError:
        self.cmbCities.SetValue(self.customer.city)
```

In essence what you should not is the Clear() and Append() methods of the ComboBox and the fact that this function is called from an event somewhere. Hope it is what you are looking for.